# TypeError: 'coroutine' object is not subscriptable in python Quart Framework

Tags: python-requests

```
from quart import Quart, request, render_template, jsonify
import json
import os, sys
import pandas as pd
import requests
import asyncio

from pylon.model.db_models import RawFiles
from pylon.orm import db

app = Quart(__name__)

@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
async def handle_form():
    f = await request.files['filename']
    f.save(f.filename)
    data = pd.read_csv(f.filename)
    data.to_json("json_data.json")
    data = pd.read_json("json_data.json")
    os.remove("json_data.json")
    os.remove(f.filename)
    print(type(data))
    print(data)
    return ""

@app.route("/")
async def index():
    return await render_template('upload.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="bheem11.arch.des.co", port=5043, debug = True)
```

I am getting one error described in title. I am working in quartz framework in python. Hoping for proper solution. Actually i am getting coroutine error when @app.route("/upload", methods = "post") execute.

Answer (score 5):

This line `await request.files['filename']` should be `(await request.files)['filename']`. Without the parenthesis everything to the right of `await` is evaluated first, which results in the attempt to subscribe (`['filename']` operation) the `files` attribute. This doesn't work as the `files` attribute returns a coroutine - which is not subscriptable. There is more on this in the [Quart documentation](https://pgjones.gitlab.io/quart/tutorials/asyncio.html#common-pitfalls).